# Past tense of "overdue"?

Tags: past-tense, phrasal-verbs

What is the past tense of "overdue"?  The context is billing/invoicing. For example I'd like to say something like this (which I believe is incorrect):

> "Invoice overdued"

Comment: Like *due*, the word *overdue* is not a verb. It does not have tenses. In the phrase *invoice overdue*, it serves as an adjective. Thus an invoice might become overdue, might be overdue, or might have been overdue. But it can't be *dued*.

Comment: Maybe this should be the answer? Or should I delete the question?

Comment: No, I shouildn't delete it as it may enlighten other readers. But it is a good idea to check things first or you may get a few fingers wagging at you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Overdue' is an adjective. Adjectives don't have tense, but it can be put in the context *of* the past by using 'was'.

'The invoice was overdue'. However, this could be interpreted in a couple of ways; for example, it could be taken to mean that the invoice was overdue at a point in the past, but that now it is *not* overdue. It could also be referring to a historical invoice in a descriptive manner, stating that, at the time of the invoice's existence, it was overdue.

It's much easier to simply use, 'Invoice overdue'. In my opinion, the inclusion of the word "was" makes it a little bit awkward, and it's largely unnecessary

Comment: If you want to emphasise the fact that it should have been paid some time ago you could put invoice well overdue.